# Enabling scrolling in scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

Is there anything that needs to be done to enable scrolling inside of a scrollview? Also, what elements can be inside of a scrollview?

Here is the relevant code. The scrollview in the first snippet seems to not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/datePick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/confirmTime"
            android:onClick="timeSelect" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/calView"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <include android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/calendar_day_view" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

calendar_day_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eightAM" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nineAM"
            android:translationY="60dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tenAM"
            android:translationY="120dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/elevenAM"
            android:translationY="180dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/twelvePM"
            android:translationY="240dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/onePM"
            android:translationY="300dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/twoPM"
            android:translationY="360dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/threePM"
            android:translationY="420dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fourPM"
            android:translationY="480dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fivePM"
            android:translationY="540dp" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sixPM"
            android:translationY="600dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        layout="@layout/calendar_horizontal_delims" />"

</LinearLayout>
```

and calendar_horizontal_delims.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:translationY="60dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="120dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="180dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="240dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="300dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="360dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="420dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="480dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="540dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

    <View android:translationY="600dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As soon as the contents of the ScrollView can no longer all fit on the screen, you will be able to scroll

Comment: You can put almost anything except a ListView inside it. Check out the android reference docs for [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in `translationY` attributes in your calendar_day_view. To be honest, this is the first time I see this way of aligning elements :)

So what is happening is that all your TextViews are basically laid out at the same `Y` position (because they are placed inside `RelativeLayout`). They are just visually translated vertically. That's why from the layout perspective, for the ScrollView the total height of your text views does not exceed scrollView's height, so that's why they do not scroll.

You have to rework your alignment a bit. First of all, change `LinearLayout` orientation to `vertical` and get rid of sibling `RelativeLayout`, so all your text views are placed inside **vertical** `LinearLayout` and try to use `marginTop` attribute instead of `translationY`

That's essentially how would your `calendar_day_view.xml` would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eightAM" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nineAM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tenAM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/elevenAM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/twelvePM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onePM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/twoPM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/threePM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fourPM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fivePM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sixPM"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <include android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        layout="@layout/calendar_horizontal_delims" />"

</LinearLayout>
```

Similar changes need to be done to `calendar_horizontal_delims.xml`

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView does nothing until the contents of the ScrollView exceed the size of the screen, at which point anything inside the ScrollView is automatically scrollable.  Almost anything can go inside a ScrollView, except things that are scrollable by default, such as a ListView.

You may want to look at the ScrollView docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Is there any reason that the contents exceed the scrollview but I still can't scroll?

Comment: `<ScrollView android:id="@+id/calView"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
                
        <include android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/calendar_day_view" />
                
    </ScrollView>`

Comment: In calendar_day_view the top component is a linear layout.

Comment: Can you please post your entire xml file by editing the question, that might be easier? Also, try changing fill_parent for layout_height to match_parent, it is more commonly used.

Comment: Your problem is that in the calender_day_view, the main layout(Linear Layout), has a horizontal orientation. This will not work with a ScrollView. Try modifying your code to remove that.

Comment: I changed that but it's still not scrolling. I'm using an emulator to try this code if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: Try changing the layout_width and layout_height of the calender_day_view to wrap_content each, that's the only other thing I can think of. The emulator should not make a difference, but you might be better off testing your app on an actual device.